# How do I use "Compress-Archive" correctly? Error message keeps saying "path does not exist or is not a valid file system path"

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am unable to use "Compress-Archive" cmdlet to compress a file called "CompressedArchive2" to "CoolArchive2.zip". I have tried several ways but The error message says the path either does not exist or is not a valid file system path.  I double checked the path using GUI and PowerShell(ls ~\desktop) and "CompressedArchive2" does exist.

```
Compress-Archive-Path C:\Users\User\Desktop\CompressedArchive2\ Destinationpath C:\Users\User\Desktop\CoolArchive2.zip
```

```
Compress-Archive -Path ~Desktop\CompressedArchive2\ ~Desktop\CoolArchive2.zip
```

Comment: Leave a space between `Compress-Archive` and `-Path`. For the 2nd parameter, you forgot to prefix it with a `-` sign. Make a habit of quoting your paths, because if it should contain space characters, things will go ugly. To get the desktop path, better use `[Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")` and use [Join-Path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-3.0). Your code works if written as: `Compress-Archive -Path 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\CompressedArchive2' -Destinationpath 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\CoolArchive2.zip'`

Comment: in addition to the many errors mentioned by Theo [*grin*], you use `~Desktop` to refer to the current users desktop dir. that WILL NOT WORK. you should have seen red error text from that [along with similar error notifications]. the proper way to use the `~` in this case would require a path delimiter between it and the next path level - something like this >> `~\desktop` <<